# ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush не работает UWP?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp

В основном гриде указан `Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"` и если я изменяю тему в конструкторе, то там же цвета и меняются. Но когда я запускаю приложение, что на реальном устройстве что в эмуляторе, тема приложения всегда светлая, хотя я ставлю тёмную тему.

Answer (score 1):

Тема приложения указывается в файле App.xaml, а не в XAML-конструкторе.

```
<Application x:Class="MyApp1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             RequestedTheme="Dark">
```

Обратите внимание на свойство `RequestedTheme="Dark"`. Такое же свойство есть и на других элементах управления. Убедитесь, что указана нужная тема в App.xaml, а также что остальные элементы не переопределяют этого свойства на другую тему.